# Rails where is 'mail' method defined

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If I know the class name I can do something like `TheClassName.method(:mail).source_location` but I don't know the class name the method belongs to.

Where is 'mail' defined? `method(:mail)` raises

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `mail' for main:Object
```

but its written just as `mail(*args, &block)` in the code.

Answer (score 0):

`bundle open rails` was not particularly helpful as there was just a readme...
going up a directory and rummaging around I stumbled across actionmailer directory.

Its in `ActionMailer::Base`, but unless you know that in advance, I don't know how you would search for it

Comment: `mail` is an instance method so what you were looking for is `TheClassName.instance_method(:mail).source_location`. You could determine this by opening a console and typing `class A < ActionMailer::Base;end` and then `A.instance_method(:mail).source_location`